# How to connect to .accdb database from R

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

New to R and have having troubles connecting to Access databases. This is the code I am running (RODBC package loaded manually before running):

```
library(RDOBC)

conn <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='C:/db/dbNorthwind.accdb'")
subset(sqlTables(conn), TABLE_TYPE == "TABLE") 
df <- sqlFetch(conn, "tblCustomer") 
df #
```

I get the error-message:

> Error in sqlTables(conn) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel.

Know any tips on how to fix?

environment:

- 64-bit Windows
- 32-bit MS Access 2013
- 64-bit Microsoft R Open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're using is fine, your setup isn't.

You need to either use 64-bits R and 64-bits MS Access, or 32-bit R and 32-bit MS Access. You can try, however, to install 64-bits Access Database Engine, found [here (2016 version)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) or [here (2010 version)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

I have had varying results with installing both the full version of Access and the database engine (currently got Access 32-bits 2016, and couldn't install Access database engine 64-bits 2016, but could install the 2010 version by using the /passive command on the installer).

See [this blog](https://techblog.aimms.com/2014/10/27/installing-32-bit-and-64-bit-microsoft-access-drivers-next-to-each-other/) for some details on how to install the 32-bits full version and the 64-bits database engine on one machine. But as noted, results may vary.

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you saying that the installer for the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) has dropped support for the `/passive` switch and it is no longer possible to force both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of ACE for 2016 onto the same machine?

Comment: @GordThompson I didn't look up the exacts because I couldn't find them in short time. I'm just saying that I tried to use that installer with the `/passive` switch and got an error message saying I couldn't install it because I already had 32-bits Office running, so I just went for the 2010 variant because there aren't that many differences as far as I know

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft decided that too many people were breaking their Office installs by using the `/passive` switch and they just dropped it. I've always maintained that it's a "Bad Idea(TM)" anyway, otherwise why would they bother coding the installer to prevent the `/passive` behaviour by default?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Since it is currently hard to do changes on my setup (company policy), I will work with a work-around (Access connected to Excel, and R connected to Excel) until my R skills are good enough to justify attempting the 64-bits Access Database Engine approach.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about database import, but I will try to help you by telling you what I usually do.
The first thing that you have to do is to understand if you have the DSN in order to access the database. You can do it by clicking start and going to ODBC Data Source.
When you are there in the window "UserDSN" you check if there is your file. In case it is not there you just need to add it, by clicking in "add" and then you look for the driver to read your file in your case is .accdb.
In case you do not have the driver you can download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=e

After you have created you DSN then you go into R and you write this few lines of code. Here I will write an example.
I have downloaded an access file from:

https://www.599cd.com/access/studentdatabases/

Access file : Access Beginner 1

The in R I have typed:

```
library(RODBC)


odbcDS <- "PCResale Customer Database"

tmp <- odbcConnect(dsn = odbcDS)

df <- sqlFetch(tmp, "CustomerT")
```

Hope that this is of any help,

Ciao!

Comment: Thanks. Tried this as well, would probably worked if my environment was setup correctly. ("...ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application...")

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me.

```
library(RODBC)

# for 32 bit windows
# Connect to Access db
# channel <- odbcConnectAccess("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Microsoft Access/Northwind.mdb")

# Get data
# data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select * from Name_of_table_in_my_database"))


# for 64 bit windows
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Microsoft Access/Northwind.mdb")

data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select * from CUSTOMERS"))

odbcCloseAll()
```